# Determining Ability of Device to Make Phone Call (including with Continuity)

Tags: objective-c, ios9, phone-call, openurl, continuity

I have been trying to determine whether a device is able to make a phone call, including with the new iOS9 Continuity features which allow iPads to make phone calls when connected to an iPhone.  Presently my code looks something like this:

```
NSURL *call = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:1111111111"]];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:call])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:call];
}
else
{
    //show an alert
}
```

However, when I run this on an iPad (whether or not the iPad has the phone call through an iPhone enabled) the canOpenURL function always returns true.  Is there any way to distinguish whether an iPad or iOS device will make a phone call as opposed to whether it theoretically could (if a phone were connected) make the call?

Comment: i think the url sceme looks for the phone application rather than ability of making a call!

Comment: I think you're right, and I'm pretty sure that's why it's not working.  However, I can't find any method that either determines whether openURL is actually completed or determines if the device will make a phone call when prompted.

Comment: Check the return value of `openURL:`.

Comment: The return value, whether or not calls from iPhone is enabled, is YES.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I'm using a workaround that first checks canOpenURL: then attempts to make the call, An NSTimer with a delay of 1.5 seconds is called which checks to see if the application state is active, if it is, I assume the call cannot be made.